# Exponential moving averages implemented in TensorFlow's Estimator/Experiment APIs?

Tags: python, tensorflow

With the new Estimator/Experiments API combination, I struggle to find information concerning implementing exponential moving averages of variables in these models. I cannot seem to find anywhere in the source code to either the estimator or experiments base classes that should specify whether or not the GraphKeys.VARIABLES collection is gathered during the evaluation phase (which I guess should be the requirement for implementing ema, right?).

Has anyone experimented with this further?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your specific question is, but have you taken a look at [ExponentialMovingAverage](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/train/ExponentialMovingAverage) and [tf.moving_average_variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/moving_average_variables)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I have looked at those. My question was not how to do the EMA's, but if the Estimator/Experiment APIs automatically catches and restores the EMA. Probably not that clear from my original post, sorry.